# Anyone integrated MULE (ESB) into .Net platforms or WCF?

Tags: .net, esb, mule

HOw did you integrate? SOAP? etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOAP is the typical choice, but not the only. You can also integrate using REST, TCP, Database (JDBC on the Mule Side), etc. For a recent Mule implementation, a MicrosoftMQ connector for Mule was developed and is available, but you need to contact [MuleSoft](http://www.mulesoft.com/) to get it.

Comment: I have not, but looked a little at the code. It builds on top of the http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-interop open source project to create a Mule connector that can read and write messages to MSMQ queues.

Answer (score 3):

Mule itself is a java based ESB that needs to run a JVM.  As for integrating it within the .NET platform... well you can't really :D.  What you can you do is implement SOA Integration Patterns in mule to work with your ASP.NET web apps, .asmx services, etc. etc.

Mule (or any ESB really) is meant to live in an heterogeneous environment and orchestrate SOA between everything that you need to have integrated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a WCF service
2. Consume using the Mule ESB

Here's the link to this: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/consuming-net-wcf-soap-web-services-from-mule/